# Fragments when rendering Volumetric Lighting in Eevee

Tags: volumetrics, eevee-render-engine

Ive tried rendering several shots using Volumetric option in Eevee but only in one case I encountered this error, where my volumtetrics get all choppy and fragmented. [image]
I tried all sorts of settings, increasing sampling of render and volumetrics, turning off Density for the Principled Volume shader, just leaving Emission on, etc. I always get this choppy result.
Can anyone point me in a direction of a possible solution please? :-)
UPDATE: Weird thing is, this also happens when I turn off volumetrics completely... No idea what this is. Anyone experienced anything similar?

Comment: Do you mind sharing the file?

Comment: Please do not add "solved" as part of the title. Mark the answer as **accepted** instead. Please take the [tour] to understand how the site works. Read also: [what does it mean when an answer is accepted?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer)

Comment: Ouch sorry, Ill do better next time ;-)

Answer (score 2):

I solved the riddle, fortunately :-) From some reason, in the compositing section, a Glare option with Ghosts settings got activated. It probably got set up automatically when I was  fiddling with Eevee rendering settings? Anyway, I manually unconnected the node and that solved the problem :-)[image]